# How to write long logical expressions in the code?

Tags: code-formatting, business-logic

Every now and then I am seeing this kind of expressions in the code:

```
return 
    _fastSkipAvailable && 
    !FastSkipInProgress &&
    !_reroutingInProgress && 
    !_someService.IsWayPointSkipDisabledForThisContract();
```

And, actually, I've been wondering if there any other way of handling this kind of scenario nicely. Maybe there is a library that allows to express it some other way or somehow hide the ugliness of such expressions somewhere.

Maybe there is something as nice as Poly (https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) which allows simplifying the code by adding nice try-retry-fallback patterns (instead of implementing ugly try-catch-finally sections by ourselves).